# How do I put a toggle on this AHK script?

Tags: loops, toggle, autohotkey

I'm fairly new to AHK and I was wondering how to put a toggle on this script so I can pause it immediately with XButton1 but also reactivate it at the same point in the loop if that is possible. I've tried looking for solutions but none of them suite my case here especially with trying to pause a loop.

```
XButton1::
SendInput {LButton down}
Loop, 27
{
    SendInput {w down}{a down}
    sleep 17500
    SendInput {w up}{a up}
    mouseMove, 52, 0, 20, R
    SendInput {w down}{d down}
    sleep 17500
    SendInput {w up}{d up}
    mouseMove, -52, 0, 20, R
}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're just simply looking for [`Pause`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Pause.htm).
For example, toggling pause with <kbd>Esc</kbd> as your hotkey:
`*Esc::Pause`

Edit:
Just noticed you mentioned <kbd>XButton1</kbd> being the pause key as well.
Does it have to be like that? It's surely doable, and I can show how to do it, but makes the thing a whole lot easier if you just have a different key for pausing.

Comment: That is totally fine if the pause key is different. How about making it XButton2? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you can make it XButton2. `*XButton2::Pause`. And in case you didn't know, [`*`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard) is for making the hotkey work even if other modifiers are held down, e.g. `Ctrl`, `Shift`, or `Alt`.

Comment: The pausing works perfectly but is there any chance to have {w up}{a up}{d up}{LButton up} when it does pause so the entire script no longer sends inputs at all.